# DOMDocument getelementbyid conflict?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javascript popup that "successfully" employs php to load another page as a DOMDocument and "successfully" finds a  element by id to display its text using nodeValue...BUT...the nodeValue call returns NOT the text inside the desired element but the text inside an anchor tag with the same name.  Here's some of the code:

the html and php that seemingly "works":

```
<span style="position:relative;"><span id="favelas" class="popup">

<?php

// Create a new DOMDocument object
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// Validate our document before referring to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;

// Load the key terms and identifications html file
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('http://teachers.dadeschools.net/jzoeller/APHG/0-Key-Terms-Identifications.html'));

// Print in readable form the content the element by id
print_r($doc->getElementById('favela')->nodeValue);

?>

</span><a href="javascript:void(null);" onMouseover="ShowPop('favelas');" onMouseout="HidePop('favelas');">favelas</a></span>
```

Now, what "should" be displayed is the definition of the term favela from the page referenced in the code above.  What I'm getting is merely the word "favela".

Here's some more code, this time from the page loaded by the php:

```
<tr>
<td><a name="favela">
favela</a></td>
<td class="def" id="favela">A shantytown or slum, especially in Brazil.</td>
<td>07</td>
<td>06</td>
</tr>
```

Debugging with var_dump gives me this:

> object(DOMElement)#1 (17) { ["tagName"]=> string(1) "a" ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> >NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(1) "a" ["nodeValue"]=> string(8) " favela" >["nodeType"]=> int(1) ["parentNode"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" >["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> string(22) >"(object value omitted)" ["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" >["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" >["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL >["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> string(1) "a" ["baseURI"]=> NULL >["textContent"]=> string(8) " favela" }

This seems to be saying that its got the anchor named "favela" and NOT the td named "favela".  What gives?!

Comment: Why is this tagged "Javascript".  Isn't this a PHP question about DOMDocument implemented in PHP?

Comment: I don't know DOMDocument that well, but I think it handles html as _html40 loose_ and there the `name` attribute of an `a` element is an ID attribute (the ID attribute does not need to have the name `id`). As of that you will find the `a`.

Comment: Okay, so, as I suspected, its tripping on the anchor; so how do I skip the anchor and get the second instance of the id, in this case "favela".  Also, thanks for the explanation.  I hope my solution is as concise!

Comment: You might have success using DOMXPath searching for `//[@id='favela']` but as I said, I don't know `DOMDocument` that well, so iI neither know if my assumption is really correct, nor if `@id`  will suffer from the same _problem_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) query instead of `getElementById()` to dodge the `name` attribute and target only the element with an `id` attribute of "favela":

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$favelaElement = $xpath->query('//*[@id="favela"]')->item(0);

print_r($favelaElement->nodeValue);
```

Output:

```
A shantytown or slum, especially in Brazil.
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to step away from the project for a few days...but your solution works.  Only one minor quibble: the authoring software I use seems to be very sensitive to the use of quotation marks, so I found that I had to replace this: ('//*[@id="favela"]') with this: ("//*[@id='favela']").